# Stripe is Creating Duplicate Customers when checkout using Different Cards

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, stripe-payments

I am working with stripe using .NET Core. and I am having an issue with if Let's say I have a customer in the Stripe with `email=test@test.com` and he has used a `visa` card for the first checkout.

And then he is trying to purchase another Item using a different card (let's say `Master Card`) then Stripe is creating a duplicate customer(*With same Email id*) for that checkout with the same email. While I want to add this new purchase Item to the existing customer even he has used different cards.

> **NOTE**:- If I use same card for each checkout for that customer then It
>   works as expected.

I am using Stripe Checkout Session Service for the Checkout process. And creating Customer only If there is no customer exist in stripe for the given Email. But in case I used different Card for the checkout. stripe is creating duplicate Customer implicitly.

This is my create customer to Stripe code

```
           // Create customer object   
            var customerOptions = new CustomerListOptions()
            {
                Email = user.UserName
            };
            // get list of customers with matching options (should be one since email is unique)
            var customers = await customerService.ListAsync(customerOptions);
            // get first matching customer
            var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault();

            // if we didn't find the customer, we create one in stripe
            if (customer == null)
            {
                customer = await customerService.CreateAsync(new CustomerCreateOptions
                {
                    Email = model.StripeEmail
                });
                newCustomer = true;
            }
```

And This is Checkout session creation logic

```
        var sessionOptions = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            BillingAddressCollection = "auto",
            CustomerEmail = customer.Email,
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
                "card",
            },
            SubscriptionData = new SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
            {
                Items = subscriptions
            },
            SuccessUrl = "https://localhost:44xx/Shop/CheckoutConfirmation?sessionId={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            CancelUrl = "https://localhost:44xx/Shop/Cart",
        };

        try
        {

            var sessionService = new SessionService();
            Session session = sessionService.Create(sessionOptions);

            response.IsValid = true;
            response.SessionId = session.Id;
            return new JsonResult(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.IsValid = false;
            return new JsonResult(response);
        }
```

Comment: Actually if you noticed above, if I use same card for each checkout for that customer then It works as expected. So I am looking for a way to stop this duplication customer creation  even I used multiple cards fro the checkout.

Comment: Thanks for your support.  I am using Stripe Checkout Session Service for the Checkout process.
And creating Customer only If there is no customer exist in stripe for the given Email. But in case I used different Card for the checkout. stripe is creating duplicate Customer  implicitly.

Comment: I look forward to seeing your code in your [mcve].

Comment: I have added required source code for you, please have a look :)

Comment: What was the **exact** value of `user.UserName` for the second request? What was the **exact** value of `customer`? _Don't guess - reproduce if necessary._

Comment: user.UserName= user email and customer have the stripe data response of a customer

Comment: I suspect you need to set this ID - https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer .

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass 'customer' when creating the Session, instead of 'customer_email'. You can use 'customer_email' for the first time a user will create a Session (meaning when you don't know already what is the customer's stripe id. Then pass 'customer' instead of 'customer_email', once you already have a customer stripe id. This will make sure your user is not duplicated on the Stripe dashboard.

Comment: I was reading your reading your useful answer ans I'am trying to match with Stripe documentation. 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions

Now we are sending only those:

 1. client_reference_id 

 2. customer_email 
 Reading your answer I see that we could use this:

 1. customer string. 

Our team created and end point to validate if the user exists at Stripe, and we receive it if exists :

           {
                "id": "cus_NKMd1kkrBTtZk",
                .....
            }
For customer Should I send the id string that I receive from this end point?